# identifying "similar" datasets by their curves with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, comparison, similarity, graphing

Consider the following

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'y':np.sin(np.linspace(1,100,10000)),'x':pandas.date_range('2019-01-01','2020-01-01',periods=10000})
df.index = df['x']
```

now in aggregate form 1

```
#this cut might not be exactly right ... but i dont have the actual code in front of me at the minute... the idea should be clear however
df['y'].groupby(pd.cut(df.index,1400)).agg('mean') # cut into 1400 equalish bins
```

and in version 2

```
df['y'].resample("3H").agg('mean') # cut into 3 hour bins
```

these two are really the same dataset, and the curves should be the same ... but whats a good method to validate that the curves are the same(ish) without plotting them and visually examining them (current method)

you can visually identify the sameness in the following graph (the blue line is one aggregation the yellow is another)

[image]

the motivation here is that the developer may mistakenly use the wrong aggregation (sum instead of mean, or maybe the wrong precision rounding)

and being able to validate that the outputs are roughly equivalent programmatically would be a huge boon

(see also https://repl.it/@JoranBeasley/EvilAwfulSimulation for a runnable example)

one idea I had is to try and segment up the chart into N pieces and use np.trapz on each subset of the x axis and compare the values

another idea might be to check the normal distribution of each subsection of the x axis... so far I have not had much success with either method

Comment: what about we "re-bin" it to very small intervals and then do `np.allclose` on the two histograms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Introduction

Good question! This a common problem in signal processing. Let's build out an understanding of what to consider. Some assumptions are:

- **There is no actual equivalence, so we must described how much dissimilarity is permissible**. Often, this will look like a threshold on a dissimilarity measure; if the measure is less than a certain value, the signals are similar enough to be considered equivalent.
- **There is ambiguity in timespan. If the signals don't share timespans, then multiple interpretations can occur**. We can discard the signal information over the disjunct timespans and focus on just the overlapping times. Also, we can **correlate** the signal to find optimal overlap between signals. Alternatively, we can penalize when a signal is active outside the region of interest. In this case, we will assume that the signals are close enough in timespan to not need to preprocess them.
- **The equivalence should be insensitive to time length**. That is, the dissimilarity measure should be normalized to the length of time to not cause varies results if the signals are lengthened. For uniform time sampling, taking the mean of some quantity of error achieves this as sample count is directly proportional to time span.

### Implementation

Let's consider a naive approach. Let's use a measure on the difference of the two signals to get a notion of dissimilarity. Once we have subtracted the two signals, the signal power can be calculated by taking the sum of squares of the values. As mentioned, this value should be normalized by dividing by the number of points involved. To summarize:

1. Resample both signals, using a sufficient sampling rate determined by signal theory
2. Subtract the two signals now that both have values at the same time steps
3. Calculate the power by accumulating the square of the difference signal
4. Normalize this value, using the MSE is commonly done
5. The two signals are equivalent if they are less than a predefined value, inequivalent otherwise

In code,

```py
def naive_equivalence(y0, y1, thresh=1e-3):
    """ for signals with identical timespans, use MSE of signal difference to determine equivalence """
    from scipy.signal import resample
    num = max(len(y0), len(y1))
    t0, x0 = decompose_timeseries(y0)
    t1, x1 = decompose_timeseries(y1)
    x0r, t0r = resample(x0, num, t=t0)
    x1r, t1r = resample(x1, num, t=t1)
    diff_pow = np.sum(np.abs(x0r - x1r)**2) / len(x0r)
    return diff_pow < thresh
```

This approach has problems. Namely, it is sensitive to

- **time skew** -- if two signals are identical but shifted in time by a small amount, we might want to consider them equivalent. In this case, the difference signal can still be large if this occurs, meaning that no equivalence will be reported.
- **time slew** -- two signals might have similar features, but happen over different time spans and rates of change. Feature-wise, the signals might be considered the same, and if this is to be tested, the naive approach would be insufficient.

This can be addressed using **dynamic time warping**, which can be [read about here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping). An example approach would be,

```py
def dtw_equivalence(y0, y1, thresh=1e-3):
    """ use notion of distance from dtw to show equivalence
    """
    from tslearn.metric import dtw
    num = max(len(y0), len(y1))
    t0, x0 = decompose_timeseries(y0)
    t1, x1 = decompose_timeseries(y1)
    x0r, t0r = resample(x0, num, t=t0)
    x1r, t1r = resample(x1, num, t=t1)
    meas = dtw(x0r, x1r)**2 / len(x0r)
    return meas < thresh
```

### Code

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_data():
    df = pd.DataFrame({'y': np.sin(np.linspace(1,100,10000)),'x': pd.date_range('2019-01-01','2020-01-01', periods=10000)})
    df.index = df['x']
    y0 = df['y'].groupby(pd.cut(df.index,1400)).agg('mean') # cut into 1400 equalish bins
    y1 = df['y'].resample("3H").agg('mean') # cut into 3 hour bins
    return y0, y1


def decompose_timeseries(y):
    return np.array([(t.right.value if type(t) == pd.Interval else t.value)/10**9 for t in y.index]), np.array(y.values)


def naive_equivalence(y0, y1, thresh=1e-3):
    """ for signals with identical timespans, use MSE of signal difference to determine equivalence
    """
    from scipy.signal import resample
    num = max(len(y0), len(y1))
    t0, x0 = decompose_timeseries(y0)
    t1, x1 = decompose_timeseries(y1)
    x0r, t0r = resample(x0, num, t=t0)
    x1r, t1r = resample(x1, num, t=t1)
    diff_pow = np.sum(np.abs(x0r - x1r)**2) / len(x0r)
    return diff_pow < thresh

def dtw_equivalence(y0, y1, thresh=1e-3):
    """ use notion of distance from dtw to show equivalence
    """
    from tslearn.metric import dtw
    num = max(len(y0), len(y1))
    t0, x0 = decompose_timeseries(y0)
    t1, x1 = decompose_timeseries(y1)
    x0r, t0r = resample(x0, num, t=t0)
    x1r, t1r = resample(x1, num, t=t1)
    meas = dtw(x0r, x1r)**2 / len(x0r)
    return meas < thresh


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    y0, y1 = get_data()
    print("Is Naive Equal: ", naive_equivalence(y0, y1))
    print("Is DTW Equal: ", dtw_equivalence(y0, y1))
    plt.plot(*decompose_timeseries(y0))
    plt.plot(*decompose_timeseries(y1))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: wow! nice answer ... i will have to dig in a bit, but dang nice answer +1 before even digging into it

Comment: this seems like it will do the trick ... I dont think i need dtw, the naive one seems like it will do just what I wanted .... even though theres some wiggle room on determining appropriate threshold for different charts than this simplified sin example, I think this certainly helps me greatly to quantify the similarities... I expect i will be accepting this solution and awarding you the bounty tomorrow... Thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: can you possibly clarify why num is max(y0,y1) instead of min? it seems like it would be better to downsample the larger one than upsample the smaller one, but its likely I am missing something?

Comment: I skipped over this detail :P long story short is the [sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist–Shannon_sampling_theorem). I can produce a different signal, that after being downsampled, is identical to the other signal. Most strictly speaking, this approach only works with [band limited signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandlimiting), a typical assumption made.

Comment: An even safer assumption is to sample at one over the shortest length between two points in time.

Comment: about the bounty... :P

Comment: awarded ... is there a good technique to come up with a threshold to use ... this threshold works very well for this example, however some of my other traces are dealing with numbers closer to 1k (some of the datasets) , and clearly those have much bigger MSE... is there some generally accepted rule of thumb? like `(max-min)*1e-3` ?

Comment: There are rules of thumb. In some electrical engineering tasks, I've seen 5% (0.05) of the signal range (max-min). But, the precision you seek is dependent, of course, on how much precision your problem requires.